# Can not read property 'enabled' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

In the code. I have to set the values fr the controls in a reactive form.

```
ngDoCheck() {
   setControlValues();
}

ngChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
   setControlValues();
}

private setControlValues() {
   try {
   theForm.Controls['class'].setValue(myValue); //error happens here
   // ...many controls
   }
   catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
   }
}
```

However I got the exception.

> Can not read property 'enabled' of undefined at eval (forms.js:4852) at(forms.js:4873) at eval(forms.js.4793) at Array.forEach() at FormGroup._forEachChild......at FormControl.AbstractControl.updateValueAndValidity (forms.js: 3393)

The form is defined as

```
theForm: FormGroup;
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.useForm = this.fb.group({
    class: [null]
 });
}
```

My html is:

```
<texearea kendoYextArea
     formControlName="class" required></textarea>
```

**Updated:**

I found forms.js code in the library has the following.

```
 AbstractControl.prototype.updateValueAndValidty =
 function(opts) {
    if(opts == void 0) { opts = {}; }
    this._setInitialStatus();
    if(this.enabled ) {
        this._cancelExistingSubscription();
```

Comment: seems there's no use of the word `enabled` in the code you posted ... is `forms.js` one of your files?

Comment: No. I don't know where is coming from. Maybe from the angular dependency framework?

Comment: I gather there's no more "trace" in that error that can trace to a line of your code? You obviously only posted a small part of your code, what made you think that was the part responsible for the error?

Comment: And I am not sure `ngDoCheck()` or `ngOnChanges` are bad guy? Because the form is in the child component. The forms.js is from `webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/forms/esm5/forms.js`

Comment: @JaromandaX, the exception occurred when set form control value. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still no clue. but if I use

```
 theForm.Controls['class'].patchValue(myValue)
```

Then the error is gone.